# How can I render data from an api to html using handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, handlebars.js

I have a problem. How can i render api data that I get from a GET request and showing it on my website using handlebars? data contains an image and a description.

Here is my code in the index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');

/* GET home page. */
const menClothing = router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     request('URL', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        console.log(body)
    });
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Website', categories: menClothing });
});
```

And here is my index.hbs code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row py-5">
        <div class="col-lg p-3">
            <h4>Clothing</h4>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3>Subcategories</h3><hr>
    {{# each categories }}
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <img src="//Here it should be the image" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">//Here it should be the description</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">View More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

And here is the JSON data that i get from the api, I have the values but i can't show:

```
[
  {
    "image": "photo",
    "_id": "",
    "id": "",
    "name": "",
    "page_description": "",
    "page_title": "",
    "parent_category_id": "",
    "c_showInMenu": true,
    "__v": 0
  },
{
    "image": "",
    "_id": "",
    "id": "",
    "name": "",
    "page_description": "",
    "page_title": "",
    "parent_category_id": "",
    "c_showInMenu": true,
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: You gotta set the view-engine in Express, something like app.set('view-engine', 'handlebars'), and then use app.engine() if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an article I found](https://medium.com/@waelyasmina/a-guide-into-using-handlebars-with-your-express-js-application-22b944443b65) by searching "javascript express handlebars".

This uses a package `npm install express-handlebars`.

Like @danibrum mentioned, you define handlebars as the `engine`. The article has a good overview of how it all works.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
//Loads the handlebars module
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
//Sets our app to use the handlebars engine
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
//Sets handlebars configurations (we will go through them later on)
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({
layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',
}));
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
//Serves the body of the page aka "main.handlebars" to the container 
//aka "index.handlebars"
res.render('main', {layout : 'index'});
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening to port ${port}`))
```

Comment: Hi, tnx for that link but i still can't import data into my handlebars. I edited the code